# Angular 5 / Jasmine 2 test setTimeout function only once

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine2.0

my problem is that i have this fonction :

```
    loopPingAPI() {
    this.pingAPI().then(
        success => {
            this.setConnected(true);
            this.stopPingAPI();

            return true;
        }, error => {
            this.setConnected(false);
            return true;
        });
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.loopPingAPI(), 5000);
}
```

There is a setTimeout (the fonction launches every 5000 ms), i try to test it like this :

```
      it('should not call the stopPingApi function', fakeAsync(() => {
            connectivityService.loopPingAPI();
            flushMicrotasks();
            expect(connectivityService.stopPingAPI).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
```

i have this error :

```
Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.
```

Is there a way to call the fonction loopPingApi() only once and after, call the stopPingApi() fonction (this fonction kill the setTimeout by clearTimeout(this.timer) ) ?

P.S : The use of tick() / flush() in place of the flushMicroTasks() has the same result .